# Node Express - Database is created too late causing error

Tags: node-sqlite3, node-async

My problem is with creating a database. It is created too late and causes problems with further queries. I tried to use async and await but it seems it doesn't solve the problem.

```
async function storeDailyDealToDB(dailyDeal) {
    const db = new sqlite3.Database('database.db');

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const QUERY_CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS daily_deal ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT,)";
        db.run(QUERY_CREATE_TABLE);
        resolve("done")
    });

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const insert =
            "INSERT INTO daily_deal (title) VALUES (?)";
        const stmt = db.prepare(insert);
        stmt.run([dailyDeal['title']]);
        stmt.finalize();
        resolve("done")
    });

    let lastRow = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        db.each("SELECT * FROM daily_deal ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", function (err, row) {
            resolve(err == null ? {} : row)
        });
    });

    db.close();

    return lastRow
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
[Error: SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: daily_deal
Emitted 'error' event on Statement instance at:
] {
  errno: 1,
  code: 'SQLITE_ERROR'
}

Node.js v17.9.0
```

I did a lot of research and I am stuck. I read to use `Promise` but it works partially. I am not sure how to tackle this problem.

Comment: That's not how you turn things into promises - you're still running the code synchronously, then resolving before the actual work happens. Node has https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal in the box which can handle conventional patterns. You don't need new Promise very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the reference docs, of [Database#run](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback), you should pass a callback to the run method. Inside this callback, you want to either resolve or reject the promise depending on the outcome.

```js
await Promise((res, rej) => {
    db.run(..., (err, result) => {
        if (err) rej(err) else res(result)
    });
});
```

I think this is correct (untested however).

Comment: There is a missing `new` before Promise but yes, that's what I needed. Thanks for pointing me out the reference link.